# Tool to automate mass payments?

Tags: payments

I was wondering if there a tool or a sample smart contract that allows to send out a mass payment to a list of addresses?

I have a table containing

Users' ETH addresses, different amounts of ETH to send to each one of them individually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tools I know for batching payments.

- [Multisend.Org](https://multisend.org/)
- [MultiSender.App](https://multisender.app/)

I'm not sure if they work for ETH, but they should certainly work for [WETH](https://weth.io/).